# Question on Polynomials in Finite Fields

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Suppose we have a finite field $\mathbb{F}^n_q$ and a polynomial $P\in Poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n)$ such that $P$ vanishes at every point of $S\subset{\mathbb{F}^n_q}$. I'm not sure what it means for a polynomial to vanish at every single point in a subset of a field, and how this can even be possible.

Comment: How is $\;\Bbb F_q^n\;$ a field? That looks like an $\;n\,-$ dimensional vector space over the field $\;\Bbb F_q\;,\;\;q\;$ a prime. Perhaps you meant the field $\;\Bbb F_{q^n}\;$ ?

Comment: And what is $\;Poly_D(\Bbb F^n)\;$ ?

Comment: This does not require finite fields. Take the polynomial $f(x)=x^{2} - 4$ over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Take the subset $\{\pm 2\} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. The polynomial vanishes at every point in this subset; put every point of the subset into $f(x)$ and you will get 0. It is the same thing as you say of your polynomial $P$.

Comment: Let me clarify what the terms mean. $\mathbb{F}^n_q$ is a finite field in $n$ dimensions with $q$ elements. $Poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n)$ the space of polynomials with degree less than or equal to $D$, in the ring $\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_q^n$ is a surely **a vector space** of dimension $n$ over the finite field $\Bbb{F}_q$. There is also a finite field $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ that also happens to be a vector space of dimension $n$ over the field $\Bbb{F}_q$, but the difference is that in $\Bbb{F}_q^n$ there is, a priori, no multiplication turning it into a field.

Comment: For example, if $P=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ is a point in the set $S$, then the polynomial (function) $x_1-a_1$ vanishes at $P$. There is nothing mysterious about that. The polynomial (function) $x_1^q-x_1$ vanishes at all the points of $\Bbb{F}_q^n$, because all the elements of $\Bbb{F}_q$ are zeros of $x^q-x$. Sometimes you need to keep the distinction between polynomials and polynomial functions very clear, sometimes it is a bit blurred. Anyway, to each polynomial there is a polynomial function, and that function can have value zero at some point.